# Problem showing the view when I add a parameter in my Route - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I want to pass a parameter to my controller from an URL, my code is:

- In **web.php**:
      Route::get('infoPatient/{id}','patientController@infoPatient');
- In my controller **patienController.php**:

  ```
  public function infoPatient($id){
    $d=patientModel::find($id); 
    return view('/patient')->with('d',$d);
   }
  ```

  As a result, the view show data without any style.
  the view:  https://ibb.co/GCr66zk

Comment: What do you mean without any style? Can you post your Blade template?

Comment: try passing blade file name in view() instead of route /patient. & also pass variable as ->with(['d'=>$d]);

Comment: can you provide show link

Comment: Reply to Serge: I mean that the view show line of data like in the picture, ![Valid XHTML] (https://ibb.co/GCr66zk).

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
    public function infoPatient($id){
  $d=patientModel::find($id); 
  return view('patient',compact('d'));
 }
```

and in your `patient.blade` file use variable `$d` to get the data

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: the probleme appear when I add "/{id}" in the route !

Comment: can you show error message or screenshot of error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

the probleme was solved, the issue was that I forget "/" in all link of bootstrap files.

Thank's.